# Do you know ASP.NET Core run on AppHarbor cloud?

Tags: asp.net-core, appharbor

I made a small application with ASP.NET Core, I pushed to github and copied from github to [App Harbor cloud](https://appharbor.com) and there should compile and publish, in the log file i see that when makes build on App Harbour cloud says that doesn't find `.sln` file. The question is that this cloud knows to build, run ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppHarbor - ASP.NET Core Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033081/appharbor-asp-net-core-support)