# AppHarbor - ASP.NET Core Support

Tags: asp.net-core, appharbor

Does AppHarbor support ASP.NET Core?

When I tried to deploy my sample application (From the Visual Studio 2015 RC templates) I got the following build log in AppHarbor:

```
Build started 5/4/2015 2:28:38 PM.
     1>Project "D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\ASPNetTest.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
     1>Project "D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\ASPNetTest.sln" (1) is building "D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\src\ASPNetTest\ASPNetTest.xproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
     2>D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\src\ASPNetTest\ASPNetTest.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
     2>Done Building Project "D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\src\ASPNetTest\ASPNetTest.xproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\ASPNetTest.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

       "D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\ASPNetTest.sln" (default target) (1) ->
       "D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\src\ASPNetTest\ASPNetTest.xproj" (default target) (2) ->
         D:\temp\g3zdb4oh.rcv\input\src\ASPNetTest\ASPNetTest.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.03
```

The code that I tried to deploy was this:
https://github.com/yngndrw/ASPNetTest

I'm not sure if I missed something or if AppHarbor doesn't support this yet ?

Comment: Even though [AppHarbor claims Stack Overflow is a great place to get support](https://appharbor.com/page/support), you should raise a ticket with them for specific questions like this.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a ticket and will update once I hear back from them: https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/77692-appharbor-aspnet-5-vnext-support

Answer (score 1):

[Rune](https://support.appharbor.com/users/573939) from AppHarbor has [responded to my question](https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/77692-appharbor-aspnet-5-vnext-support#comment_36779319):

> Hi,
>
> ASP.NET 5 / vNext and .NET 4.6 is not officially supported yet as they are still at the RC state - official support will be rolled out and deployed across all servers when they reach RTM. Note however that for vNext / ASP.NET 5 application you may still be able to run those applications on AppHarbor, but for now you'd have to work around the missing build targets projects, as those are not currently available on AppHarbor's build servers.
>
> AppHarbor will continue to support earlier versions of the .NET Framework including 4+, and there are no plans to discontinue support for applications requiring those frameworks when vNext and .NET 4.6 is officially supported.
>
> We may also introduce beta support or guidelines for deploying apps using the newer frameworks prior to the official RCs. I'll make sure to update this thread if/when we do this.
>
> Best,
> Rune

I will update further once support is added. Thanks.

Comment: Some days ago was release .NET Framework 4.6. When the AppHarbor support the new .net and asp.net 5? Thaks

Comment: According to [this other support ticket](https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/79972-aspnet-5-support) in December, [Rune](https://support.appharbor.com/users/573939) mentioned that support should be in place but it isn't currently officially supported. It was however mentioned that now that RC1 is out they have started work on supporting it better.

I've just tried it now and got the same "`DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props` not found" error as I did last time but you might be able to use `DNVM` to install the required stuff now as a pre-built step. (I've not tried doing this)

Comment: I [also tried](https://github.com/cottsak/mvc6inprod/commit/f366ba57158a43b0c50b9471b83486f340653fe3) and it's still broke with `Microsoft.DNX.Props" was not found`. That [other post](https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/79972-aspnet-5-support) which mentions the [Roslyn/C# 6.0 hack does work to get MVC5 stuff into AH](https://github.com/cottsak/DevCookie/commit/6b9a1f2e32ef5e6a03d02728bc9318ca88534f24) but it doesn't work for MVC6!

Comment: Any further update on the DNX issue?

Today (26th April 16) I tried and got his response

"...xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."